# Just trying out to check whether the value is present in array or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function in jQuery.

```js
var arr1 = ["Jcob", "Pete", "Fin", "John"];
var str = $("#fname").val();
if (jQuery.inArray(str, arr1))
  $("#lname").text("Bob");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

Please check my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7gotkmfp/1/)

What it will do it the user will give the value in the first input box the jQuery function will check if the value is present in that array it will fill the second input box with the given text.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/#jQuery-inArray-value-array-fromIndex  `inArray` returns the index of the value found, or -1 if not found.  With regards to your current logic, `-1` is a truthy value.

Comment: What if someone enters 'pete' or 'JOHN' or 'FiN'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1. You need to add an **event listener** to the first input to *constantly keep checking* when someone inputs something.
2. Before selecting elements in the DOM, make sure the DOM is ready.
3. You don't need jQuery at all here. Like most things, very easy to do without jQuery.

```js
const names = [ "Jcob", "Pete", "Fin", "John" ];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const fname = document.getElementById('fname');
  const lname = document.getElementById('lname');
  fname.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    lname.value = names.includes(fname.value) ? 'Bob' : '';
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

If you insist on jQuery (which I do strongly recommend you shouldn't until you are proficient with the native DOM API):

```js
const names = [ "Jcob", "Pete", "Fin", "John" ];
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $fname = $('#fname');
  const $lname = $('#lname');
  $fname.on('input', function(event) {
    if ($.inArray($fname.val(), names) > -1) {
      $lname.val('Bob');
    } else {
      $lname.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
```

Comment: what if I have multiple arrays and to display multiple names according to the first name presence in each array.

Comment: Please ask a new question, that is not in scope of the original question here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body>

    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
    <button onclick="checkValue()">Click</button>

    <script>
        var arr1 = ["Jcob", "Pete", "Fin", "John"];

        function checkValue() {
            var str = $("#fname").val();
            var val = jQuery.inArray(str, arr1);
            if (val === -1) {
                console.log("no value");
            }
            else {
                $("#lname").val("Bob");
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```